# Why this div tag is getting an margin automatically when I write some content inside that div tag?

Tags: html, css, inline

```html
<div style="background-color: black;width: 100%;height: 300px;margin-bottom: 30px;">
    
    <div style="width: 30%;background-color: green;height: 100%;display:inline-block;">
            ddsddsd sd sd sddsa
    </div>
    <div style="width: 30%;background-color: yellow;height: 100%;display: inline-block;">
        
    </div>


</div>
```

I have added a small text inside the green inner DIV tag .suddenly it moved to the down.
The same issue happens even when I add another div tags inside that inner div tag.
If I remove that inner text then this green div tag will act normal just like that yellow tag.
I am not understanding why. Why HTML is acting illogically.. I don't think this has any logical reason.. I feel like quitting HTML..

Answer (score 5):

This is because `inline-block` comes with another handy property called `vertical-align` and by default, your boxes are not vertically set. So by giving them both `vertcial-align: middle` will solve your issue.

```html
<div style="background-color: black;width: 100%;height: 300px;">
    
    <div style="width: 30%;background-color: green;height: 100%;display:inline-block;  vertical-align:middle;">
            ddsddsd sd sd sddsa
    </div>
    <div style="width: 30%;background-color: yellow;height: 100%;display: inline-block; vertical-align:middle;">
        
    </div>


</div>
```

[Wroking Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r39Ly7qv/)

Comment: so why by default, the div element moves to the bottom ?  Any why my yellow DIV tag didnt moved to the bottom ?

Comment: Because your yellow `<div>` doesn't have text it has to align.

Answer (score -1):

The `div` tag in HTML by default gives a margin on all 4 sides of the text and you need to normalize the margin using css.

```
{
  margin: 0;
}
```

Also to make sure there is no padding too you can modify your css code to

```
{
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
}
```

Comment: `div` does not have default margins in any modern, halfway relevant browsers.

Comment: I applied it right now and it gives a by default 8px margin on all sides in Chrome.

Comment: That is the default margin of `body` that you are talking about then. (And still doesn’t change the fact, that your “answer” here has rather little to do with the specific problem that was asked about.)